# How does one map network drive from windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, network-drive

I'm trying to map network drive from windows service, I use batch file for executing the following command

```
NET USE U: \\192.168.55.6\folder password
```

While executing batch file either in service constructor or in onstart event, drive is not mapped?

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\MAP.BAT";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.Start();
```

How does one map network drive from windows service?

Comment: I don't know why your connection is failing, but why not make the mapping directly from your code, rather than shelling out to net.exe? http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html will give you an error code that will help you to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All issues solved by using [Map Network Drive (API)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mapnetdrive.aspx) to map network drive. I map required drives while OnStart event of service.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using a reference to Windows Script Host Object Model.

Add a COM reference to **Windows Script Host Object Model** which adds an entry IWshRuntimeLibrary to the references section. Now you can use the following code to map a drive.

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class();
network.MapNetworkDrive("k:",@"\\192.168.20.35\MyShare", Type.Missing, "user1", "password1");
```

you can use the following code to UnMap or remove the mapping.

```
network.RemoveNetworkDrive("k:");
```

I have documented the detailed steps [here](http://techisolutions.blogspot.com/2011/12/map-network-drive-using-c-vbnet-code.html)

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to just call the right API function, instead of calling a batch file to call another executable. The function you're looking for is [`DefineDosDevice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363904%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. Mappings are only in use for the user session, which means that effectively you can't use a mapped drive for a Service.  You would need to use the [unc](/questions/tagged/unc) path.
2. The second issue is that a service (using the local system account)
   does not have access to the network, or more specifically, to the
   resource required.  To resolve this, you would need to, either: Give
   the 'computer' on which the service is running specific access to
   the folder, or, set up the service to use a network (DOMAIN) account
   that has access to the resource.

Comment: If anyone requires more detail (or proof:)): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think services can't map network drives unless they have the right "interact with desktop" ?

Try to run the service under the "Network Service" account, instead of "Local System" ?

Comment: Can you log the output of the map command? like: "net use ... > c:\map.log"

Comment: This shouldn't matter I think - network mappings are not managed by the shell. They're kernel-level links. See WinObj from SysInternals.

Comment: My understanding is that the user and the service use the same list of mappings, so that changes from the service could impact the user.  Hence the requirement for "interact with desktop".  My knowledge here is a bit dated tho (> 8 years :D)

Comment: Would be severly different nowadays. Drive letters are associated with the user session; the desktop is associated with a "WinStation".

Comment: Any other suggestions rather than pinvoke?

Comment: How do you notice the drive is not mapped?  If what MSalters says is right, you won't see a drive mapped by a service in explorer. Because they're in a different user session.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the service under the user account that belongs to the password? The `MAP USE` command will use the current user, unless you pass /USER:anotheruser

Comment: Yes. And this user account has permissions on that shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a mapped drive is only mapped for the duration of the user session. If your windows service is running on startup, or is otherwise not part of a user session, the drive mapping is lost.

This may or may not be true but it is worth looking into - I remember something about it from a similar scenario I had about 7 years ago.