# access to network share from windows service using WebClient

Tags: c#, security, windows-services, webclient

I need to create windows service that would:

1. download some files from uri (google.com, \\localnetwork\share, etc) using WebClient
2. stop, remove, install, start other windows services
3. create some local files

what account should my service use? 
local service(what about 2 and 3) ? local system (service have to work with \\localnetwork\share)? my user with specific rights?

update

one more option is to use local system account and [map network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792868/how-does-one-map-network-drive-from-windows-service) (if it is file://uri), but this is [not recommended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180362/en-us)

anyone? please

Comment: Only 2 (and *maybe* 4 if it supports PUT) seem likely; why have you decided that WebClient is the tool to use here?

Comment: it wasn't my decision. but anyway what's wrong with WebClient?

Comment: If you need access to SMB shares (\\server\share), you'll need something like "NETWORK SERVICE", not a "LOCAL..." account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a purpose built user with the appropriate rights to the network shares and local file system.  It should only have the rights necessary to run as a service and accomplish those goals.

Comment: WebClient works for me with \\server\share. where did you get info about webclient and SMB shares?

Comment: anyway, my own investigation showed that the created user with the appropriate rights is the most right approach